# Fourier transform with compact support!!

Tags: fourier-analysis

Suppose f is of moderate decrease and that its fourier transform $\hat{f}$ is supported in $I=[-1/2,1/2]$. If $\chi$ is the characteristic function of $I$,then show
$\hat{f}(\xi)=\chi(\xi)\sum_{-\infty}^\infty f(n)e^{-2\pi in \xi}$.

I just do not see how we can have a sum instead of an integral. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Recall that $f(x)$ is of moderate decrease if there exists a constant $A>0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq \frac{A}{1+x^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\hat{f}(\xi)$ has compact support it means you can write it as

$$
\hat{f}(\xi) = \chi(\xi) \hat{g}(\xi)
$$

where $\hat{g}(\xi)$ is a periodic function, with period $f_0 = 1$. Since $\hat{g}(\xi)$ is periodic in $\left[-1/2,1/2 \right]$ you can write the Fourier series, whose coefficients are

$$
f(n) = \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \hat{g}(\xi)e^{-i2\pi n \xi}d\xi = \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \hat{f}(\xi)e^{-i2\pi n \xi}d\xi
$$

therefore

$$
\hat{f}(\xi) = \chi(\xi) \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}f(n)e^{i2\pi n \xi}
$$

Comment: The "moderate decrease" tells you the Fourier transform exists, because at least $f$ is in $L^1$ and therefore it's Fourier transform exists.

Comment: What did you use in your last step? I thought the fourier inversion formula used only integrals, not sums..

Comment: Do you agree with me that $\hat{f}(\xi) = \chi(\xi) \hat{g}(\xi)$ where $\hat{g}$ is some periodic function in $[-1/2,1/2]$? you can easily construct such a function.

Comment: Assuming "yes" as answer, do you agree with me that since $\hat{g}$ is periodic then you can write $\hat{g}$ as $$\hat{g}(\xi) = \sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}} c_n e^{i 2\pi n \xi}$$?

Comment: Therefore you can substitute that expression in the one I gave for $\hat{f}$ in terms of $\hat{g}$, there's no inversion involved. The only subtlety to be observed is that since $|f(x)| < A/(1+x^2)$, then $f(x) \in L^2$, therefore by Parseval $\hat{f}$ is in $L^2$, and therefore $\hat{g}$ is in $L^2(I)$ therefore you can write the Fourier series.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Whittaker-Shannon interpolation formula] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula)

under the form you can find in the upsaid article :

$$f(t)=\underbrace{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}f(n)\delta(t-nT)}_{f(t) . III_T(t)}\ \star \text{sinc}(\frac{t}{T})$$

(III means Dirac comb) with $T=1$ and then take the Fourier Transform of both sides using the facts that the Fourier Transform of

- a convolution product is an ordinary product.
- Dirac $\delta(t-n)$ is (by translation rule) $FT(\delta(t-n))=\underbrace{FT(\delta(t))}_{=1} e^{-2i\pi n\xi}.$
- $t \mapsto $ sinc $(t)$ function is $\chi \mapsto \chi(\xi)$ function.

Comment: Doesn't this approach require to know a little bit about distributions?

Comment: Yes, of course, but only the most elementary one, the Dirac distribution which is usually met rather soon in lectures on Fourier Transform, at least for students that are in engineering studies. Your answer [+1] has the advantage to use only Fourier series.

Comment: @user8469759 Yes, but only because of the needlessly abstruse _notation_! Juust write $\text{sinc}((t-nT)/T)$ in place of that convolution and the need for distributions goes away.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich You are perfectly right. But sooner or later using  Dirac's distribution and the Dirac comb is conceptualy a simplification.